# Change the xlab" in the plot from the bayesboot function

Tags: r

```
# install.packages("bayesboot")
library(bayesboot)
dat <- data.frame(tee = c("de", "gf", "ss", "oi", "po", "pe"),
                   too = c(32, 45, 22, 98, 9, 255))

bp <- bayesboot::bayesboot(dat$too)
```

When I try to plot the results the xlabel does not change.
Do I need to modify the arguments inside "bayesboot" function or there is another way to make it?

```
plot(bp, ylab = "testY", xlab = "testX")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `bayesboot:::plot.bayesboot` is internally using `attr(bp, "statistic.label")` as `xlab` and overwrites your command. Change it.

```
bp <- bayesboot::bayesboot(dat$too, mean) 
attr(bp, "statistic.label") <- "testX"
plot(bp, ylab="testY")
```

[image]